# Difference between standard outer left join and join using select

Tags: oracle, select, outer-join

Is there any difference between these two statements:

```
 -- Statement 1:
 SELECT *
 FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

and

```
  -- Statement 2:
  SELECT *
  FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, a, b, c FROM Table2) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

I'm not an expert but statement 2 just looks like poorly written sql, and like it would take much longer.  I'm attempting to optimize a code block and it has many joins like the second one. Are they technically the same and I can just replace with the standard join statement 1?

Thanks!

Ps. This is Oracle, and working with 100's of millions of rows.

PSS. I'm doing my own detective work to figure out if they are the same, and time differences, was hoping an expert could explain if there is a technical difference what it is.

Comment: If Table2 has more than 4 columns, then statement 2 is to just restrict the result set. Less data is supposed to be faster to load.

Comment: The explain plan is your friend.

Comment: @DVJex: the second one only restricts the number of columns, but not the number of rows.

Comment: The second query is equivalent to `SELECT t1.*, t2.id, t2.a, t2.b, t2.c FROM Table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id` if those are all columns of table2 then both queries are 100% identical and Oracle will almost certainly use the same execution plan for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not same queries, with the lack of a criteria in the subquery that depends on whether the all columns and all column names of the `TABLE2` is involved in the subquery. If the subquery involves all of the column names of the `TABLE2` in the select list then they are the same query and the subquery is unnecessary. With subquery I refer to the part with a select statement after the join statement in the parens.

The first one uses the `TABLE2` with its all columns, all those columns will be available in the result set where the criteria met.

However in the second one the table you make the `JOIN` is not the `TABLE2` of yours but a table with just columns from `TABLE2` specified in the subquery's `SELECT` list, namely `id`, `a`, `b`, and  `c`. But it will have all the rows after this subquery since no criteria is enforced on it by  a `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

You will have same number of rows with only selected columns participating from the `TABLE2`.

The second one is not necessarily the poorly written one. You could have a criteria to met before you `JOIN` to the `TABLE2`.

Comment: Interesting thank you.  Sounds like they are different, in that one gives access to all columns in Table2 as statement 2 only gives access to columns id, a, b, and c.  Would the fact that the second one is a sub query add time to the query, or no?  I guess i'll have to experiment to find out if one is any faster than the other.  Thanks!

Comment: @russd I am not sure whether it will add extra delay to the query if u use the subquery. But since there is no criteria, `where` clause in the subquery you can omit it altogether. If you want to give access, or show only some of  the columns of the `TABLE2`, just put those columns in the first `SELECT` list as:
`SELECT
   t1.*,
   t2.id,
   t2.a,
   t2.b,
   t3.c
 FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id`. You do not need a subquery for this.